# set default value of dropdown to No

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a xslt code,where we are taking dropdown values from xml file.Now i want to default the value of dropdown to NO.

below is the code:

```
<td colspan="2" align="left">product:


                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//infor/item/" mode="dropDown">
                      <xsl:with-param name="xmlListFile">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$"/>xyz.xml
                      </xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: Please show us minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code and HTML (?) output you want and the one you currently get. Showing us an `apply-templates` without the relevant template creating the "dropdown" doesn't allow us to understand what your code does.

Comment: Below is the xml file and output now am getting is blank one because in xml file first option is empty.                                                                 <yesnoempty>
<items>
 <item short=""></item>
 <item short="Y">YES</item>
 <item short="N">NO</item>
</items>
</yesnoempty>

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have given, the default value can be set to 'NO' as following:
Though it's required to know your specific implementation and content you have as said by @Martin Honnen

```
   <xsl:variable name="dropDown_Value">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//infor/item/" mode="dropDown">
            <xsl:with-param name="xmlListFile">
                <xsl:value-of select="$" />xyz.xml
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$dropDown_Value != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="$dropDown_Value" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'NO'" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

However, it's necessary to know detail of your requirements. Please edit your question accordingly. Don't put the code in comments.